# Can I see the entire document when zooming the document using webkit-transform?

Tags: javascript, css, web, webkit, zooming

I zoom the document using webkit-transform as below.

```
document.body.style.WebkitTransform = 'scale(2)';
```

Then, below code for resizing scrollbar to see entire document doesn't work.

```
document.body.style.overflow = 'scroll';
```

I tried below codes instead, however they don't work.

```
document.body.style.overflow = 'auto';
```

or

```
document.body.style.webkitOverflow = 'scroll';
```

Was the document cut off after zooming?(If so, I can't see the entire document.)
 Or do you have any ideas to see entire document after zooming like resizing scrollbars?

Comment: The document needs no scrolling since you 've already zoomed it , for for the scrollbar to appear you need to apply extra paddings and margins

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Is there any sample codes to apply extra paddings and margins? I don't know when and how I must apply extra paddings and margins.

Comment: It depends on how much did you zoom the document in the first place , perhaps if you post more code on the element being zoomed , _I could look into it_ , But roughly it appears that you 've zoom it *upto twice* its size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Fahad, I could solve my question.
 Fahad adviced me to apply extra paddings and margins. I tried some paddings and margins. And I found that applying extra margins is solution. Applying extra margins, I can scale up the whole body regardless of the transformOrigin. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

On a second thought , I think you what you need is the **[Transform Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin)** ,

> The **transform-origin** property lets you modify the origin for
> transformations of an element

Suppose in your example above this is what you wanted

```
document.body.style.WebkitTransform = 'scale(2)';
```

Now try playing with the width and the height of the document , perhaps that will fix the view and the scroll bars will appear ...

```
var v_scale = 2.0;
document.body.style.transformOrigin = 'top left';
document.body.style.transform = 'scale(' + v_scale + ')';
document.body.style.width = 100 * v_scale + "%";
document.body.style.height = 100 * v_scale + "%";
```

By default, the origin of a transform is "50% 50%", which is exactly in the center of any given element. Changing the origin to "top left" (as indicated above) causes the element to use the top left corner of the element as a scale point.

Values can be lengths, percentages or the keywords `top, left, right, bottom,` and `center`, just try to explore them untill you find the one that suits your needs.

Just out of curiosity, why are you scaling up the whole body?
Cheers

Comment: Thank you very much!! I tried your code. When I try the code with `document.body.style.webkitTransformOrigin = 'top left';`, I can scale up the whole body. However when I try the code with `document.body.style.webkitTransformOrigin = '50% 50%';`, I can't scale up the whole body in spite of writing `document.body.style.width(height) = 100 * v_scale + "%";`. Is there any 
necessary code when origin isn't "top left"? And answering "> why are you scaling up the whole body? ", I feel necessary to see the whole body after zooming. Now my code is inconvenience for this reason.